# If there are two O(n^2) and one O(n) snippets in a single program what is the complexity of the program

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

What would be the time-complexity and how to calculate.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can we assume that the snippets execute independently of one another (e.g., that one O(n^2) snippet isn't nested inside one of the other snippets)?

Comment: As asked, the question is not answerable: it depends how the snippets are used and what the rest of the program is. Better would be to describe a specific problem you're trying to solve rather than a somewhat underspecified and generic problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
T(n) = O(n^2) + O(n^2) + O(n)
     = O(2n^2) + O(n) // add terms
     = O(2n^2) // n^2 is dominant over n
     = O(n^2) //remove constant factor
```

Answer (score 0):

If they are combined so they are done sequentially (i.e. each of the snippets is executed once), then total complexity is summed, and you can simplify as follows:

`O(n^2) + O(n) = O(n^2 + n) = O(n * (n + 1)) = O(n) * O(n+1) = O(n) * O(n) = O(n * n) = O(n^2)`